# Sonar Error: Use try-with-resources or close this "ZipOutputStream" in a "finally" clause

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I implemented a zip download method in a Spring Boot application with Java. I tried several different solutions but I am still receiving: *Use try-with-resources or close this "ZipOutputStream" in a "finally" clause error* from Sonar.

Here you can find my implementation in the service. I would be so happy if you can direct me to solve this issue!

```
@Override
public void downloadZipBySeasonId(int seasonId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
.
.
.
    if(!items.isEmpty()) {
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = null;
        try {
            zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());  // Sonar points this line!
            for (int i = 1; i <= items.size(); i++) {
                LetterEntity letter = items.get(i - 1);
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(letter.getLetterName());
                zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                StreamUtils.copy(letter.getLetterContent(), zipOut);
                zipOut.closeEntry();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not zip succesfully!");
        }
        finally {
            if(zipOut != null) {
                zipOut.finish();
                zipOut.close();
            }
        }
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + zipFileName + "\"");
    } else {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why try-with-resources is a very good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying try with resources to initial code would be as below. Here you don't have to close the stream in a finally block. It's closed when try catch block is exited. Sonar issue was there because of the null check.

```
 if(!items.isEmpty()) {
        
        try (ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());){
            for (int i = 1; i <= items.size(); i++) {
                LetterEntity letter = items.get(i - 1);
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(letter.getLetterName());
                zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                StreamUtils.copy(letter.getLetterContent(), zipOut);
                zipOut.closeEntry();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not zip succesfully!");
        }

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + zipFileName + "\"");
    } else {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

Comment: That solved the problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try with ressources close the ressources automatically (ressources like Streams , Buffereds..)
you dont need to close the readers or writers in the finally block , you dont need to write the finally block , also you can avoid writing the catch block..

example

```
 try (BufferedReader r = Files.newBufferedReader(path1);
  BufferedWriter w = Files.newBufferedWriter(path2))
 {
  //protected code
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
  // exeption handler
 }
```

documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped to solve the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Try with resources is a very beautiful concept, it takes away the pain of closing the resources in finally block that's also a few extra lines of code for you to write.
Try with resources automatically closes the resources, making your code concise and taking care of closing resources in any situation.

**Syntax:**

```
    Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(new File("scan.txt"));
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (scanner != null) {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

**try with resources:**

```
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("scan.txt"))) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    fnfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped to solve the issue!